# Use Symfony2 without its authentication system?

Tags: php, symfony

I want to implement an authentication system with a username and password of the users table.

I have 2 other tables and `users_type1` `users_type2` that contain a foreign key to the users table (`fk_users`).
My goal is to identify during the authentication if the user matches the type 1 or type 2 in order to redirect properly.

With the Symfony authentication system, I can not do it.

If I code everything myself without using the Symfony system, so I managed to do what I want.

My question is: What do you think to use Symfony2 without its authentication system?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Symfony's `RoleInterface` to group users by their roles.

[Symfony's documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#managing-roles-in-the-database).

You can also control the redirect [from a form parameter](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/form_login.html#control-the-redirect-url-from-inside-the-form).